# understanding tensorflow sequence_loss parameters

Tags: tensorflow

The `sequence_Loss` module's [source_code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/seq2seq.py#L1075) has three parameters that are required they list them as outputs, targets, and weights.

Outputs and targets are self explanatory, but I'm looking to better understand is what is the `weight` parameter?

The other thing I find confusing is that it states that the `targets` should be the same `length` as the outputs, what exactly do they mean by the length of a tensor? Especially if its a 3 dimensional tensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used this in a class and our professor said we could just pass it ones of the right shape (the comment says "list of 1D batch-sized float-Tensors of the same length as logits"). That doesn't help with what they mean, but maybe it will help you get your code to run. Worked for me.

This code should do the trick: `[tf.ones(batch_size, tf.float32) for _ in logits]`.

Edit: from TF code:

```
for logit, target, weight in zip(logits, targets, weights):
      if softmax_loss_function is None:
        # TODO(irving,ebrevdo): This reshape is needed because
        # sequence_loss_by_example is called with scalars sometimes, which
        # violates our general scalar strictness policy.
        target = array_ops.reshape(target, [-1])
        crossent = nn_ops.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            logit, target)
      else:
        crossent = softmax_loss_function(logit, target)
      log_perp_list.append(crossent * weight)
```

The weights that are passed are multiplied by the loss for that particular logit. So I guess if you want to take a particular prediction extra-seriously you can increase the weight above 1.

Comment: It helps a bit, but I'm trying to understand more about whats the purpose of the weights parameter, Im not finding a lot of discussion of weights in the loss function of an RNN, unless we're talking about the output layer. Do you happen to know the answer to the proper shape question pertaining to what length means?

Comment: I guess you're talking about the comment in the code? `weights: List of 1D batch-sized float-Tensors of the same length as logits.` Is your question about that comment?

Comment: that would be the one.

Comment: @TheM00s3 I updated my answer (see the last sentence).

Comment: @TheM00s3 I found the code that uses the weights, maybe that's helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Think of the weights as a mask applied to the input tensor. In some NLP applications, we often have different sentence length for each sentence. In order to parallel/batch multiple instance sentences into a minibatch to feed into a neural net, people use a mask matrix to denotes which element in the the input tensor is actually a valid input. For instance, the weight can be a `np.ones([batch, max_length])` that means all of the input elements are legit.

We can also use a matrix of the same shape as the labels such as `np.asarray([[1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,0],[1,1,1,1]])` (we assume the labels shape is 3x4), then the crossEntropy of the first row last column will be masked out as 0.

You can also use weight to calculate weighted accumulation of cross entropy.